# Configure Checkstyle ImportControl module

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm trying to use the `ImportControl` module with Checkstyle and Maven, but `mvn checkstyle:check` fails with:

> Failed during checkstyle configuration: Property 'file' does not
> exist, please check the documentation

All files are in the root of my project:

`pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

`checkstyle.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
  "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
  "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="ImportControl">
  <property name="file" value="import-control.xml"/>
</module>
```

`import-control.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE import-control PUBLIC
    "-//Checkstyle//DTD ImportControl Configuration 1.4//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/import_control_1_4.dtd">

<import-control pkg="a.b.c">
  ...
</import-control>
```

I am confused by the error message. Does this mean that the config file cannot be found, or that the property `file` itself is invalid? According to the [documentation](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html#ImportControl) my config should be correct. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

With the info provided the error could be that in checkstyle.xml. You need to reference the whole location. Something like this, ${basedir} to reference the root directory

```
<module name="ImportControl">
  <property name="file" value="${basedir}/import-control.xml"/>
</module>
```